# Fail to upload jar file to jcenter: 405 code

Tags: gradle, groovy, maven-plugin, jcenter

I have the following `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin:'groovy'
apply plugin:'eclipse'
apply plugin:'maven'

configurations {
  deployerJars
}

repositories{
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

version '0.1.2'
group 'io.example'

dependencies{
  implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.10'    
  testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'      
}

dependencies{
  deployerJars "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.2"
}

uploadArchives {
  repositories.mavenDeployer {
    configuration = configurations.deployerJars
    repository( url:'https://my-private-repo.bintray.com' ){
      authentication userName:'myName', password:'secret' }
  }
}
```

If I run the task, I'm getting an exception:

> Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
>
> > Could not publish configuration 'archives'
> >
> > > Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ...... Return code is: 405, ReasonPhrase: Method Not Allowed.

I tried using `maven-publish` plugin with no luck either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Any insight?  I have the same issue

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese I switched to packagecloud.io, adjusted my config accordingly and it's working like charm. Interested?

Comment: Thanks I also got it figured out.  I'm using nexus and the server requires a different URL for artifact uploads and downloads.  So I just found out the correct upload URL